# Plugin single.php not showing

Tags: wordpress, templates

I'm creating a plugin for Wordpress that creates a new post type for news and events (yes, yet another one ;-) ). The post-type is registered under the name gg_nae.

The post type works as expected; the post type can be saved and edited.

Now I want to create a custom template file. I called it single-gg_nae.php and I saved it in the same folder as the plugin-code.
If I understand the explanation on https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/working-with-custom-post-types/ correctly that should be enough to render the post type in the custom template, but it won't. It renders the post with the single.php file from the template.

If I move the custom template to the theme-folder however, Wordpress uses the template as intended; it renders the post in the single-gg_nae.php template.

What am I doing wrong here? Should single-gg_nae.php be placed in a specific folder in the plugin-map?

edit: I already saved the permalink-structure again, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking all wrong when approaching this issue.

I have created custom post types before and always included them in the functions.php of my Wordpress theme, therefor creating templates (archive-PostTypeName.php and single-PostTypeName.php) to show them. I assumed that was also needed when developing a CPT-plugin.

In case of a plugin, however, you have to alter the behavior of the single.php template from within the plugin using filters. I have added the following (simplified) code to my plugin:

```
/**
 * Alter the_content if Posttype is custom post type
 *
 * @uses is_single()
 */

add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 20 );

function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {
if ( is_single() AND get_post_type() === 'PostTypeName') {
    // Do stuff here
    $content = 'This is My Custom Post Type!';
 }

// Returns the content.
return $content;
}
```

When opening posts of the type 'PostTypeName' the content will say 'This is My Custom Post Type!', otherwise it'll show the content of the post of page.

More information about filters (and actions) can be [in the Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks)

Answer (score 0):

only for the missing in this three below parameter u are getting error

```
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'slider' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => true,
```

try it in argument list with rest of parameters

Comment: Those arguments are already in the register_post_type function. And I'm not getting an error, the plugin only uses the wrong template.

Comment: create your template in theme's folder and paste the below code in plugin core file.
Replace the post-type with your post type name                              <?php
    function get_custom_post_type_template($single_template) {
    global $post;

       if ($post->post_type == 'my_post_type') {
          $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/post-type-template.php';
       }
    return $single_template;
    }
    add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_custom_post_type_template' );
?>